# Forward search with WinEdt when compiling PDF

Tags: forward-inverse-search, winedt

There is a forward search option (<kbd>Shift+F8</kbd>) with WinEdt 7 which works well for me, but it is only to visualize a previously compiled PDF.

I am looking for a way to force a new compilation of the PDF when doing a forward search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to start a forward search in your `.pdf` file each time you compile your files.

To do that in WinEdt 7 (BTW WinEdt 8 with folding capabilities and other new features has been released) go to "Options" -> "Execution Modes". The following dialog interface appears:

[image]

Depending on the tool you are using to compile your documents, select it from the list and check both "Start Viewer" and "Forward Search" under "Process Flow" (if not checked yet).

If you want this behaviour for all the compiling tools, you can press the "Apply to All" button under "Process Flow".

Now, next time you compile your document, you will be redirect to the right point in your `.pdf` file (*forward search*).

---

Remember that these settings are saved only for the "configuration" in which you're working on.

If you change the configuration through one of the commands in "Options" -> "Configurations" you will have to set the above settings in the new configuration, as well.